# How to measure performance/load time of dashboard charts?

Tags: charts, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to do performance testing over dashboard which contains different types of charts in a web page. All I have is JMeter now and I want to improvise the testing for dashboards / charts.

Kindly suggest me your ideas on how to do performance testing over multiple charts in a web page.

We are using Jasper Reports for data fetching and charts are made using JS components.

I need to measure the charts total load time of all the charts along with data i.e. I need to measure load time with complete UI loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you seen [Performance Testing with JMeter](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/performance-testing-jmeter) chapter? It explains how you can use JMeter for recording your scenario in browser and converting it into JMeter .jmx script.

JavaScript doesn't do any magic, it generates HTTP requests which can be intercepted with JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and replayed with increased load later on.

I would only suggest considering using [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter) as [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) requests are often being executed asynchronously (in parallel) and well-behaved JMeter test must act exactly like real user using real browser.

Comment: Can you tell me how to include static content while running already recorded jmx file ?